# How to check support for ext2 filesystem on android device

Tags: file-system, ext2

I have a android mobile with gingerbread 2.3.4 installed.

I want to know if my device(kernel) supports ext2 filesystem. Is there any terminal command to check the support for ext2 filesystem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cat /proc/filesystems` is the typical Linux/Unix way of determining this. It works fine on CyanogenMod, but I'm not sure about other ROMs. If you want to filter out all of the other supported filesystems you could `grep` the output, too (assuming you've got `grep`, of course):

```
# cat /proc/filesystems | grep 'ext*'
    ext2
    ext3
    ext4
#
```

Comment: Thanks. The output is showing nodev word before some filesystems, what is nodev???

Comment: @sam: Taken from [Redhat's documentation](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-filesystems.html): "The first column signifies whether the file system is mounted on a block device. Those beginning with nodev are not mounted on a device." You'll usually see "virtual" filesystems with the `nodev` flag, I believe (like `sysfs` or `rootfs`).

Answer (score 0):

Download Debian Tools to check which ext your phone supports

Comment: This might be a useful recommendation if you add a link to the tool you're recommending.