# Which filesystems with wear leveling does Android support?

Tags: sd-card, file-system

So I bought 64gb micro SD card which was formatted as exFAT. I can't use it with Android and I am actually very happy now that I have a good reason to get rid of this ms crap. In particular I do not want to use FAT32 or NTFS because neither of these have a **[wear leveling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling)** functionality.

- Which **filesystems** with **wear leveling** does Android support?

Comment: I'm not an expert in file system at all, but when researching this topic, I found it hard to give definitive answer, mostly because people argued that wear-leveling on mobile device is not the biggest concern. Some explained that [wear-leveling is implemented on hardware level](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/software/mobile-linux/22579-google-android-gingerbread-is-using-ext4?p=262964#post262964), or [software level below the file system](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=21158205&sid=90b942cddd8ce2f03cdb511a42b0a568#p21158205)...

Comment: (cont'd) also, a relevant question on Super User: [Is flash drive wear a significant issue?](http://superuser.com/questions/31324). There must be a reason why you want this (you haven't mentioned it, but I assumed it's to improve SD card performance?). That said, [YAFFS2](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=21157843&sid=90b942cddd8ce2f03cdb511a42b0a568#p21157843) and [ext2](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18824/how-to-check-support-for-ext2-filesystem-on-android-device?rq=1) were used *by Android*, but as file system on SD card, I'm not sure.

Comment: Support for filesystem varies by device and firmware. Individual manufacturers/ROM modder may decide which filesystem they support from a wide range that Linux supports. So what's your device model? And do you use stock or custom ROM?